# Magnifying lens for embedded image

Tags: html, iframe

Does anyone know how to add a magnifying lens (like [this](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3)) to an embedded image?

This is my embed code:

```
<a href="http://wip.weather.gov.sg/wip/pp/gif/rghz.gif">
<img src="http://wip.weather.gov.sg/wip/pp/gif/rghz.gif" alt="Regional Haze Map" title="Regional Haze Map" width="700"/>
</a>
```

The image is showing wind currents using arrows, but it is too small for viewing, so I would like to add a magnifying lens to make the viewing easier.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. On your linked page, click 'view code'

Comment: But how and where do I add the code into this: <a href="http://wip.weather.gov.sg/wip/pp/gif/rghz.gif">
<img src="http://wip.weather.gov.sg/wip/pp/gif/rghz.gif" alt="Regional Haze Map" title="Regional Haze Map" width="700"/>
</a>